# Acessando propriedade privada com decorator em typescript

Tags: typescript, private, decorator-pattern, protected

Em Typescript, é possível acessar uma propriedade privada pelo decorator?
Um exemplo do código que já fiz

```
class A {
    @dec
    private _teste: string = 'teste'

    constructor(){}

    public get teste() {
       return this._teste + '1'
    }
}
```

```
function(target: any, key: string){
    const value = target[key]  //sempre retorna undefined
}
```

No decorator nao consigo acessar nem o valor e nem a propriedade em si. Existe alguma forma de conseguir acessar e manipular a propriedade _teste?